# GStreamer 'rawvideoparse' element reads wrong amount of bytes

Tags: gstreamer

I'm reading a byte-stream YUV420 at 972x720 pixels from a file with Gstreamer using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testfile blocksize=1049760 ! rawvideoparse width=972 height=720  framerate=1/1 ! xvimagesink
```

This works in so far that I get an image but it isn't displayed correctly. When exporting the frames seperately using command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testfile blocksize=1049760 ! rawvideoparse width=972 height=720  framerate=1/1 ! multifilesink location="rvp_%d.raw"
```

I see that when using the element 'rawvideoparse' it will create a file of 1051200 bytes per frame instead of the expected 1049760. When I remove 'rawvideoparse' the frames are exported correctly but my objective is to read them directly from the file into an 'xvimagesink'

Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [GStreamer Development mailing list](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Is-rawvideoparse-element-reading-the-wrong-amount-of-bytes-td4693001.html) I got an answer. The problems was that the rawvideoparse element can't handle this resolution. When I switched to 976 width it works.